# Cannot use sass command line due to "List" casting not found

Tags: node.js, npm, sass

Trying to use sass for my application. I installed it using "npm install -g sass". But after that, I still cannot use it giving me the following error:

```
(venv) ruben@xxx:~/Projects/my_project/node_modules/bootstrap/scss$ sass --version
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:1997
throw H.e(H.cH(a,function(e,f){return e.replace(/[^<,> ]+/g,function(g){return f[g]||g})}(z+y,init.mangledGlobalNames)))},
^

TypeError: Instance of 'dz': type 'dz' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>'
    at dart.e (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:1629:3)
    at dart.c (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:1997:9)
    at dart.fh (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:10234:19)
    at dart.tK (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:1597:69)
    at dart.fy (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:5690:28)
    at dart.Cd (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:7278:10)
    at Object.run_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:7266:42)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sass/sass.js:8:7)
    at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
```

The requirements of my current machine are:

```
npm --version => 3.5.2

node --version => v4.2.6

ubuntu => 16.04 LTS
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the same problem. A quick search gives me another stackoverflow thread with the same problem. Both from today.
I have uninstalled the version 1.7.0 (published 3 days ago) and installed 1.6.2 : 
`npm install -g sass@1.6.2`

Hope it helps,
Enric

Answer (score 1):

Install `npm install -g sass@1.6.2` is the correct answer.

On MacOs solution is also installing Command Line Tools:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Answer (score 0):

If node_modules already existed when you installed sass then you need to rebuild it, there are a number of ways to do it but I tend to cd into the root folder and run

rm -r node_modules && npm install

I believe there is also a rebuild command that should also fix the issue